# Sending data from an app to a database

Tags: java, android, api, heroku

im currently trying to get my android app to send some data up to a heroku server but im not sure how to do this. Ive made the class below to hold the data that im sending. I have this data saved in a sqllite database , i just dont know how to take this info and send it to the heroku server ( im assuming to there api?) and im assuming that ill have to put this data in  a json.

```
public class Observation {

    int species;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    public Observation(int species,double latitude,double longitude){
        this.species=species;
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public int getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }

    public void setSpecies(int species) {
        this.species = species;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: ty , i will look at this!!